# PDF binary data output in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, web-services, pdf

I have a question about outputting PDF files. Currently I'm storing the PDF in the database in binary form. I'm outputting the PDF file via a URL such as:

```
http://myhost.com/FileManager.aspx?FileId=8465b2f9-b64e-4a9a-a449-94b5adb3b278
```

so from what I could deduce, to the browser this is an .aspx page that is loading and not a PDF. Firefox and IE interpret this correctly and launch Adobe Acrobat, however since Chrome (12.0.742.112) has its own implementation of a PDF reader, it will open the file correctly, but then when someone goes to save the file in chrome, it wants to save it as a .aspx. If I simply rename the .aspx to .pdf, the file downloads correctly. However, I"m trying to avoid telling my customer that s/he may have to take that extra step.

When I chose to look at the headers that loaded in Chrome via Web Inspector, I see this:

> FileManager.aspx:-1 Resource interpreted as Document but transferred
>   with MIME type application/pdf

I can completely understand why Chrome would say this.

Furthermore, I get a save as box upon page load when I add:

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=blah.pdf");
```

However, I was hoping to just keep the file in a browser. So aside from using some URL Rewrite, is there a way I can manipulate the HTTP Headers to simply open the page as a PDF and save correctly in Chrome?

Lastly, I tried using a WebService, but I can't seem to write the binary data to the page.

```
this.Context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the web application's top-level web.config, add the following `<add>` element to the `<httpHandlers>` section:

```
<httpHandlers>
    <add verb="*" path="FileManager.pdf" type="ProjectName.FileManager" />
```

...where `ProjectName.FileManager` is the full name (namespace and classname) of the `FileManager` class in `FileManager.aspx.cs`.

This tells ASP.NET to handle the path `/FileManager.pdf` using the handler defined by `ProjectName.FileManager`. (`System.Web.UI.Page` implements the `IHttpHandler` interface, so every webform is a handler.)

Now you can serve the PDFs via a URL with a **.pdf** extension like so:

`http://myhost.com/FileManager.pdf?FileId=8465b2f9-b64e-4a9a-a449-94b5adb3b278`

You do *not* need to rename the physical `FileManager.aspx` file. When the user enters /FileManager.**pdf**?FileId=foo in the browser, ASP.NET will handle the request with the ProjectName.FileManager class defined in FileManager.**aspx**.

**Note:**

The above should work on **Cassini** (the Visual Studio "mini" webserver) with no further changes. However **IIS** by default only sends *.aspx, *.asmx, *.ashx requests to ASP.NET. Therefore, for the above to work on IIS, you need to tell it to send requests for `/FileManager.pdf` to ASP.NET. That is, you need to configure a "mapping".

With IIS 6 you need to [configure the mapping using IIS manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc783552(v=ws.10)).

With IIS 7 you can [configure a mapping from your web.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/handlers/add)--this makes deployment easier, but it depends on how your hosting is set up.

Comment: cool, thanks. I can't believe I didn't think of that. Anyhow your directions are slightly incomplete, to anyone else reading this, this allows me to rename my FileManager.aspx to FileManager.pdf write my URL like so: http://myhost.com/FileManager.pdf?FileId=2355235. Thanks much Justin.

Answer (score 2):

Something that worked for me was to add the intended filename between the application page name (in your case, `FileManager.aspx`) and the query mark (the `?` mark).

So, in the end, you'd have something like this:

```
http://myhost.com/FileManager.aspx/myfile.pdf?FileId=8465b2f9-b64e-4a9a-a449-94b5adb3b278
```

Surprisingly, the correct application will run (`Filemanager.aspx`), the variables will be passed unharmed (`FileId`), the result will be treated as `inline` (if you didn't change it to `attachment`, that is) but the browser will think that the filename to use, in case the user wants to save the page, is `myfile.pdf`.

Comment: That's a good idea. But I think it would still require configuration of IIS to send *.pdf requests to ASP.NET. Correct?

Comment: I'm actually on Apache =P I don't think the OP would need to change anything from the current configuration, though... I mean, if I understood correctly, the OP is able to return inline pdf's already, the problem seems to be when the user tries to save the file. Unfortunately I don't have an IIS box at hand here to give it a try =)